# Perform an action after a promise.then callback

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to encapsulate some intialization / clean up code in a single Promise. What I want if to execute some code, execute the then and then execute some more code. This is what I came up with:

```
function initialize() {
    let callback;
    console.log('intialization');
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => callback = resolve);

    new Promise(async () => {
        await callback();
        await promise;
        console.log('cleanup');
    });

    return promise;
}
initialize().then(() => console.log('execute then'));
```

which gives me the following output in the terminal:

```
initialization
execute then
cleanup
- Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
```

All good so far. However, when we make the callback async, it no longer works.

```
initialize().then(
    async () => {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    console.log('execute then');
                    resolve();
                },
                10000
            )
        })
    }
);
```

gives me this output:

```
initialization
cleanup
- Promise {<pending>}
execute then
```

I would have expected it to look like this:

```
initialization
- Promise {<pending>}
execute then
cleanup
```

How can I fix this? Is this even possible at all?

Comment: There's fundamentally no way to do this, since you don't know when the promise chain ends. What about `initialize().then(...).then(...).then(...)`?

Comment: If you want to put something in the middle of a promise chain, you should probably pass a callback to `initialize`. The code as is right now doesn't do much. It relies on asyc resolution mechanics for something to be executed at a specific place. However, as you've found out, this is *exceptionally brittle.

Comment: Is there a thought behind combining async/await and promises? As for promises, always return the result of a promise. In your example, if the setTimeout is  (instead) a promise, you should return that promise.

Comment: The setTimeout is just to fake a long running async method, the goal is to be able to pass an async method in there. Since setTimeout is not async by itself, I needed to wrap it in a promise for this example. And you can't await inside a function that is not async.

Comment: The reason I'm not just chaining `then` is because I want to obscure the final then in the chain. I do know I'll always have either one or two thens in my callback though, if that would make a difference.

Comment: It doesn't. You can only really do what VLAZ suggests: `function foo(cb) { doSomething().then(cb).then(() => console.log('clean up')) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept a callback that defines an asynchronous operation. Then it can be inserted into the middle of an promise chain:

```js
const delayMessage = (message, ms) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(message);
    resolve();
  }, ms));

async function somethingAsync() {
  console.log('intialization');
}

function initialize(callback) {
  return somethingAsync()
    .then(callback)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('cleanup');
    });
}
const middleOfProcess = () => delayMessage('execute then', 2000);
initialize(middleOfProcess);
```

It works even if there are multiple async steps to do in between, since you can simply chain them together:

```js
const delayMessage = (message, ms) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(message);
    resolve();
  }, ms));

async function somethingAsync() {
  console.log('intialization');
}

function initialize(callback) {
  return somethingAsync()
    .then(callback)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('cleanup');
    });
}

const middleOfProcess = () => delayMessage('execute then1', 2000)
  .then(() => delayMessage('execute then2', 2000))
  .then(() => delayMessage('execute then3', 2000));
initialize(middleOfProcess);
```

The same can be done using async/await syntax:

```js
const delayMessage = (message, ms) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(message);
    resolve();
  }, ms));

async function somethingAsync() {
  console.log('intialization');
}

async function initialize(callback) {
  await somethingAsync();
  await callback();
  console.log('cleanup');
}

const middleOfProcess = async () => {
  await delayMessage('execute then1', 2000);
  await delayMessage('execute then2', 2000);
  await delayMessage('execute then3', 2000);
};
initialize(middleOfProcess);
```